# Why systemd says its dependency system should be used only sparingly?

Tags: systemd, dependencies, d-bus, unix-sockets

From systemd.unit(5) man page:

> Note that while systemd offers a flexible dependency system between units it is recommended to use this functionality only sparingly and instead rely on techniques such as bus-based or socket-based activation which make dependencies implicit, resulting in a both simpler and more flexible system.

I thought people adopted systemd because it made things simpler and more flexible. Now systemd disagrees. I just received a SIGSERIOUSLY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This recommendation is intended to encourage

> a both simpler and more flexible system

*even more so* than the use of dependencies.

Dependencies are useful, but too many explicit dependencies introduce their own constraints: for example, the dependency graph has to be checked for loops. Explicit dependencies also lead to strong ordering constraints.

Imagine you have a web application which needs a local database. You could represent this using an explicit dependency: the database must be started before the web application. You could also represent this using socket-based activation: the database listens on a socket, so any access to that socket can be viewed as a request to start the database if it’s not already running. Using socket-based activation means the web application’s service description no longer needs to know about its dependency on the database, and the service manager no longer needs to wait for the database to start before starting the web application.

Comment: 1. Thanks. 2. Could the database listen before running? 3. How human would ever have an advantage over computer in checking the dependencies for loops and ordering constraints? 4. Why is this implicit approach of not knowing about the dependency "both simpler and more flexible"? e.g. How is reading the web server's and the database's manuals and fixing sockets and testing it and writing scripts to replicate it any "simpler and more flexible" over 1 line? And the maze that is created by adding other programs, and the hackish ways to make maintenance scripts "know" about every dependency, etc..

Comment: 2. That’s what systemd does for socket-activated services: it listens on the socket, and passes control to the service once it’s started. 3. I didn’t mean to imply that a human had to do any of this. 4. The expectation is that the database provides its service description with everything required. All that the web application needs to know is how to connect to it, and it needs to know that in all cases, regardless of how the database is started. With socket activation there’s *no* line connecting the client to the server in the systemd service configuration, which is simpler than one line.

Comment: Thank you very much. Had a long journey migrating to Linux and didn't have desktop, so read it using elinks and researched to better understand it, but couldn't pass the login captcha. The misunderstanding was because, when I read the man page, my research for "Linux bus-based activation" and "Linux socket-based activation" returned nothing but Linux's d-bus system and Unix sockets. So, I shouldn't have used the man page to learn systemd, or the man page should have considered the ones who don't know what systemd means by those terms before reading the man page!

Comment: About my long migration journey: Not daring it for years, learnt much and dealt with the strangest of hardware issues (on Windows, random windows were unclickable, letting mouse clicks pass through (software issue, right?), happening for the Numpad-controlled software mouse as well (software, again), which made me think Windows is indeed hijacked and Kaspersky is blind! Then I thought XFCE/xorg/Manjaro is badly buggy. It wasn't until I re-migrated to Arch that I noticed it's the very same Windows mouse issue. Switched the mouse out of wonder, and the issue stopped!